# What's the difference between частинка and частка

Tags: вживання-слів, терміни, вибір-слова

I've seen [Субатомна частинка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) and [частка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)). In English *Субатомна частинка* is *Subatomic particle* and *частка* is *Grammatical particle*. They differ in an adjective but both contain *particle* which refers either to частка or частинка.

So what's the difference between *частинка* and *частка*? Can I use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, without considering some some specific cases and actual usage-frequencies for different meanings of these words, only comparing their sets of allowed meanings, it appears that ***частка* has more meanings than *частинка***.

The generic word ***частина*** (not mentioned in your question) has two main meanings, which both are usually translated into English as *part (either a physically separated part, or a logical part of something)*. <sub>Additional meanings include *part (the largest structural unit) of a book*, *organization/company division* and *military division*.</sub>

The word ***частинка*** derives both main meanings of *частина* — usually meaning *small* part (because the word *частинка* is a diminutive from *частина*). The additional meaning of *частинка* (comparing to *частина*) is *particle as a minute fragment or quantity of matter*.

The word ***частка*** has all the meanings that *частинка* has, and in addition can mean:

- *section of a leaf*;
- *quotient (division result)*;
- *grammatical particle*.

<sub>So theoretically both *частинка* and *частка* can be used to refer a subatomic part, although practical usage-frequencies may differ.</sub>

References:

- [*частина* in “Slovnyk ukrajinsʹkoji movy” (a.k.a. SUM-11)](http://sum.in.ua/s/chastyna);
- [*частинка* in “Slovnyk ukrajinsʹkoji movy” (a.k.a. SUM-11)](http://sum.in.ua/s/chastynka);
- [*частка* in “Slovnyk ukrajinsʹkoji movy” (a.k.a. SUM-11)](http://sum.in.ua/s/chastka).

Answer (score 3):

"Частинка" and "частка" are both a diminutive form for a word "частина" - "part", as "particle" is a diminutive for "part". https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/-icle.

That is why they're indeed interchangeable.
However, as long as we are talking about science, I would recommend a certain standardization to avoid ambiguities.
For the sake of effectiveness I would take "частка" as a shorter and more formal one, and use it all over.

In a non-formal language these two words are absolutely interchangeable and you can use both to make it sound richer.